# Cassandra client UTF-8 garbled

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I use cassandra in my project, and it works well, but now I want to use cassandra-cli.bat to initialize some data(include some UTF8 words), when I run cassandra-cli.bat and input some words, the UTF8 words displayed as `????`, I don't know why, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a terminal issue, rather than specifically related to cassandra-cli.  If your terminal application supports UTF8, it should just work.  I'm not familiar with windows at all, but searching for 'UTF8 Windows terminal' gives a few hints on things you might try.